# Does xBox in developer mode supports video DRM playback with SL2000 or SL3000 content?

Tags: uwp, drm, xbox, playready

I work with device - Xbox Series S in developer mode,
OS VERSION: 10.0.25398.3491

I tried to run the video with DRM. But it does not work.

In the documentation, I find - *on development kits, there is an SL150 limit (that is, they can't play SL2000 or SL3000 content)* [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/playready-client-sdk#use-playready-drm-on-xbox-one)
At the same time, we tested xBox by the [link](https://testweb.playready.microsoft.com/Tool/Hwdrm) and saw that xBox supports PlayReady Hardware DRM with SL3000.

So, what is the current status? Can we play DRM video with SL2000 or SL3000 in devMode or not?
If this is not possible in dev mode how to do it?